# Redirect with manipulating get parms php

Tags: php

what's the best practice for manipulating a request and redirect it?

example -

user goes to `www.mysite.com?s=1&b=2`

I want to redirect to

```
www.mysite.com?s=1&b=2&c=3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the variable to the ones already passed via `$_GET` and then perform the redirect:

```
$params = $_GET;
$params['c'] = 3;

header('Location: http://www.mysite.com?' . http_build_query($params));
```

You could shorten the expression by using `$_GET + array('c' => 3)` but you get the point :)